# List prints letters and not strings?

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time getting the following to print correctly:

```
core = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
glutes = 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
upper = 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
lower = 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
conditioning = 21, 22, 23, 24, 25

core_ability = int(input("Core: "))
glute_ability = int(input("Glutes: "))
if core_ability > 4:
        upper_ability = int(input("Upper body: "))
else:
        ""
lower_ability = int(input("Lower body: "))

conditioning_ability = int(input("\nConditioning ability level:"))

newcore = core[0:core_ability]
newglutes = glutes[0:glute_ability]
if core_ability > 4:
        newupper = upper[0:upper_ability]
newlower = lower[0:lower_ability]
newconditioning = conditioning[0:conditioning_ability]

if core_ability > 4:
        movement_bank = str(newcore) + str(newglutes) + str(newupper) + str(newlower) + str(conditioning_ability)
else:
       movement_bank = str(newcore) + str(newglutes) + str(newlower) + str(conditioning_ability)

sections = int(input("\nNumber of GPP sections in the session: "))

print("\nSPECIFY THE NUMBER OF MOVEMENTS PER SECTION")

if sections == 1:
        section1_num = int(input("Section 1:"))
        print(random.sample(movement_bank[0:], k=section1_num))
```

I get an output the looks like:

```
' ', ' ', 'r'
```

when I'd like to get something like:

```
'1', '16', '8'
```

I added "str()" to each list in the "movement_bank" list because without it I got an error of: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code is very confusing and has many unnecessary parts that make its understanding even harder.  As for the problem that you encounter, please show the value of `movement_bank`. As a side note, `'16'` can never be returned by `random.sample` because `random.sample` from a string always returns single-character substrings.

Comment: Please, make sure to post a [mre]. Your code should be an *example*, i.e. it should not be your real code which includes all sort of stuff not relevant to the problem. It should be an example that demonstrates the problem *and only the problem*. It should be *minimal*, i.e. there should be nothing in there that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. And it should be *reproducible*, i.e. I should be able to copy&paste and run it, and it should be *immediately obvious* to me, *that* the result is wrong and *what* the correct result would be.

Comment: My sincere apologies, I clearly have a significant amount to learn. I do appreciate the feedback and will do my best to clear things up in the future if/when posting.

Comment: For example, it is completely non-obvious to me why `' ', ' ', 'r'` is a wrong result, nor is it obvious why `'1', '16', '8'` is a right result. Also, your code depends on external inputs, and it is totally unclear for *which* input that is the correct result. Or is that the correct result for all inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you have different lists, and want to combine them all into one list.
Use `extend`:

```
core = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
glutes = 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
upper = 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
lower = 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
conditioning = 21, 22, 23, 24, 25

movement_bank = []
core_ability = int(input("Core: "))
movement_bank.extend(core[:core_ability])
glute_ability = int(input("Glutes: "))
movement_bank.extend(glutes[:glute_ability])
if core_ability > 4:
    upper_ability = int(input("Upper body: "))
    movement_bank.extend(upper[:upper_ability])
lower_ability = int(input("Lower body: "))
movement_bank.extend(lower[:lower_ability])
conditioning_ability = int(input("\nConditioning ability level:"))
movement_bank.extend(conditioning[:conditioning_ability])

sections = int(input("\nNumber of GPP sections in the session: "))
print("\nSPECIFY THE NUMBER OF MOVEMENTS PER SECTION")
if sections == 1:
    section1_num = int(input("Section 1:"))
    print(random.sample(movement_bank, k=section1_num))
```